# Java: PrintWriter object not detected

Tags: java, printwriter

I am having some trouble getting java to recognize my PrintWriter object 'out'. I'm not really sure what the problem is.

```
public void storeInput(String fileName)
{
    String folderName = "C:/temper/testy/";

    File filetest = new File(folderName, fileName);

    System.out.println("ENTER TEXT!!!!!");
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter(filetest)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    out.println(filetest);

    out.close();


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare that outside of `try`

```
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
      out = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter(filetest)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `out` variable's scope is currently only in the scope of the `try` block.  Declare it before the `try` block so it's available after the block ends.

You'll need to initialize it to `null` so you don't get a "variable may not have been initialized" error.  Then you'll need to test if it's `null` when attempting to use it past the `try` block.

Answer (score 0):

`PrintWriter out` is visible only inside the `try` block. accessing it from outside will result in a compile error.

You can either move it's declaration outside the `try` block so that it become in you case visible in the hole body of the function `storeInput` but then you'll have to check whether ist is initialized before the statments

```
out.println(filetest);
out.close();
```

or better you move those tow statements in side the `try` block so when no exception accours `out` is always initialized.

For the `close` it is better to place it inside a `finally` block, that way you are always releasing resources no matter what exception happens.

```
public void storeInput(String fileName)
{
    String folderName = "C:/temper/testy/";

    File filetest = new File(folderName, fileName);

    System.out.println("ENTER TEXT!!!!!");
    String input = sc.nextLine();
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(
                new BufferedWriter(
                        new FileWriter(filetest)));

        out.println(filetest);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(out != null) {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```